# Retroactively refresh document names in Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

Can we "refresh" the document names in envelopes retroactively?  We've already sent out our envelopes but need to change the document names inside of the completed/sent out envelopes.  There is around a few hundred envelopes to update so updating each one individually will be problematic.  The reason we need to do this is that we have a few different envelopes but when setting up the documents inside of the envelope the documents were setup with the same name so when we receive the Document through the API the documents had the same name so each document was overwriting the previous entry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't believe this is possible.  Once an envelope has been sent and its status is "In-Process" the only aspects you can change are recipient(s), tab(s), and or custom fields (which are at the envelope level, not document level), and if it's in "Completed" status then there's nothing you can change about it.

So there's currently no way to change the document names of a sent envelope, and I'm not sure if there ever will be as that's like having someone sign something, then changing an aspect about that something that they signed underneath them.

With regards to what you CAN change once an envelope has been sent, you can edit the following recipient info:

```
email, userName, signerName, routingOrder, faxNumber, and deliveryMethod
```

And you can modify tabs for a given recipient as well.  You can also modify any envelope custom fields you might have in the envelope.  One final point I'll make, is that in our system a POST http request is always to add or create things, and a PUT http requests is for modifying existing envelopes - so whenever you are modifying a recipient, tab, or custom field make sure your requests are PUT requests.

References:

[Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm)

[Modify Envelope Custom Fields for an Envelope](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20for%20an%20Envelope.htm)

[Modify Tabs for a Recipient](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Tabs%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm)